# Segmentation fault while closing mysql connection in C++. How to resolve?

Tags: c++, mysql, segmentation-fault

I am trying to query a database using the `libmysql++` API and so far I am able to successfully run **some** queries. (reason behind **some** will be explained later)

So everything works fine, but as soon as I attempt at closing the connection and exiting the program, a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` appears, as you can see below:

```
shell> g++ -o test testCDB.cpp -L/usr/include/mysql -lmysqlclient -I/usr/include/mysql

testCDB.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
testCDB.cpp:122:74: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
  StudentManager manager1("localhost", "root", "ikilledkennedy.", "testDB"); 
                                                                          ^
testCDB.cpp:122:74: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
testCDB.cpp:122:74: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
testCDB.cpp:122:74: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]

shell> ./test
Successfully connected to the database.

Enter your query: SHOW DATABASES;

[information_schema]
[mysql]
[performance_schema]
[sys]
[testDB]

Do you wish to continue?(Y:1/N:0) : 1

Enter your query: SHOW TABLES;

[Student]

Do you wish to continue?(Y:1/N:0) : 0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

shell>
```

What's causing this issue and what measures do I take to resolve this?

Coming to the **some** queries part--there are certain queries that exit with a `Segmentation fault` too when fed to the database (like `INSERT`) which I feel is because these queries don't produce a result set and when I try to fetch rows in `displayTable()` or perhaps free the result set in `performQuery(char *)`, a `NULL` value is encountered. Am I right in thinking this or is there some other root cause?

The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <mysql.h>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

class StudentManager
{

    private:

        char *host;
        char *user;
        char *password;
        char *database;

        MYSQL *connection;
        MYSQL_RES *result;

        void init()
        {
            connection = mysql_init(NULL); 

            if(!mysql_real_connect(connection, host, user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0))
            {
                cout << "Cannot connect to the database.\n"
                     << "Please make sure you have entered the details correctly and try again."
                     << endl;
            }

            else
            {
                cout << "Successfully connected to the database.\n" 
                     << endl;
            }       
        }

        void displayTable()
        {
            MYSQL_ROW row;

            unsigned int num_fields;
            unsigned int i;

            num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result);

            cout << endl;

            while((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)))
            {
                for(i = 0; i < num_fields; i++)
                {
                     cout << "[" << ( row[i] ? row[i] : "NULL" ) << "]";
                }

                cout << endl;
            }

            cout << endl;
        }


    public:

        StudentManager(char *host, char *user, char *password, char *database)
        {
            this->host     = host;
            this->user     = user;
            this->password = password;
            this->database = database;

            init();
        }

        void performQuery(char *query)
        {
            if(mysql_query(connection, query))
            {
                cout << "Query error: " 
                     << mysql_error(connection) 
                     << endl;

                return;
            }

            result = mysql_use_result(connection);

            displayTable();

            mysql_free_result(result);
        }


        void disconnect()
        {   
            cout << "Closing connection...";

            mysql_close(connection);

            cout << "Connection successfully closed.";
        }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{   

    StudentManager manager1("localhost", "foo", "bar", "testDB"); 

    int choice = 1;

    char *query;

    while(1)
    {
        cout << "Enter your query: ";
        cin.getline(query, 256); 

        manager1.performQuery(query);

        cout << "Do you wish to continue?(Y:1/N:0) : ";
        cin  >> choice;

        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

        if(choice < 1)
        {   
            manager1.disconnect();

            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please install valgrind and run your program with valgrind. It will help you find who caused the memory error.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and replace all `char*` with `std::string`. Chances are that the problem will "magically" disappear, as will the warnings. And please don't write Java-style constructors in C++. Use initialisation lists.

Comment: @ChristianHackl .. I have worked on Java for some time now but am pretty much a beginner at C++. It's only recently that I started learning it. So, you can call it L1 interference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use uninitialized pointer here:

```
char *query;

while(1)
{
    cout << "Enter your query: ";
    cin.getline(query, 256);
```

The `query` variable is not initialized, and points to some random memory location. Most likely somewhere in the stack segment. When you write to that location using `getline` you corrupt the stack. Which leads to segmentation fault.

Since the code in question does not seem to be performance critical I'd suggest to rewrite the code like this:

```
std::string line;
while (cin.good())
{
    cout << "Enter your query: ";
    std::getline(cin, line);
```

PS there are some other issues with the code in my opinion, but since the question is about segmentation fault I'll keep my answer focused.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works like a charm! And I'd be really glad if you highlight those other issues that you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like memory corrupted early, here:

```
char *query;   // <-- uninitialized buffer 

while(1)
{
  cout << "Enter your query: ";
  cin.getline(query, 256);
```

`getline` reads data from the stream and stores it into the buffer. Buffer of proper length should be allocated by you. To fix it use:

```
char query[256];
```

> there are certain queries that exit with a Segmentation fault too when fed to the database (like INSERT) which I feel is because these queries don't produce a result set

`INSERT` query doesn't produce result set, so according to the documentation [`mysql_fetch_row(result)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-fetch-row.html) returns `NULL`. It's the correct behavior and not a reason of `Segmentation fault`.

Comment: That fixed it! I'd really appreciate it if you could be a bit more precise. And could you shed some light on the  second part of the question? Thank you, anyway. :)

Comment: @RavishAhmadKhan `INSERT` query doesn't produce result set, so according to the documentation [`mysql_fetch_row(result)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-fetch-row.html) returns `NULL`.